# Variables not assigned correctly in liquid

Tags: liquid

Please bear with me I'm new to liquid (I'm a swift programmer helping out a friend) 
This is so basic but I can't get it to work...

I have to calculate taxes on a page. This works :

```
{{ object.total_price | times: 0.21 | round:2 }}
```

and this is what I want. However I need to use that tax several times on that page and would like to assign it into a variable :

```
{% assign tax = object.total_price | times: 0.21 | round:2 %}
```

if I then use

```
{{ tax }}
```

it has the value of object.total_price and NOT the calculated result.

I played a bit and

```
{% assign test = 5 | times: 2 %}
{{test}}
```

gives me 5 and not 10

Comment: weird, your code containing filters in an `assign` should be working. are you using Shopify?

Comment: nope. Using thinx a Belgian ERP solution. Quite nice  otherwise

Answer (score 0):

In your version of Liquid 'assign' probably does not allow filters, as described here:
https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/79

I suggest this work-around:

```
{% assign test = 5 %}
{{ test | times: 2 }}
```